# Did liquid array accessors in shopify templates change recently?

Tags: shopify, liquid

For some reason this bit of liquid just stopped working in a site I did some months back:

```
{% assign packs = collections.packs.all_products %}
{{ packs[0].title }}
```

Accessing the array items in a for loop still works, but I am unable to access the items directly using an index value.  Is this a recent change to the template system or is something else going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work again. A change in liquid that caused this was reverted last week.